# How do I declare an array of multiple n-dimensional points in OpenCL

Tags: arrays, pointers, opencl

I want to pass an array of `n` mathematical vectors of dimension `dim` to OpenCL, below is the function definition.

```
__kernel void multiDimFunction(__global float** data, uint dim, uint n)
{
  // TO DO: Kernel implementation  
}
```

The function parameters `dim`and `n` are known before the OpenCL code is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to store your values in a 1D array and manually compute the linear indices. For example, to access `data(x,y)`, you would load `data[x + y*dim]`.

If `dim` was a value that OpenCL has language support for via vector types (2, 3, 4, 8 or 16), then you could potentially use an array of these types (e.g. `global float8 *data` for an Nx8 array, which you can access as `data[i].s0` to `data[i].s7`).